# как добавить placeholder в input через js

Tags: javascript

В DOM дерево нужно добавить вот такую строчку

```
<input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
```

Как мне добавить placeholder?

Вот моя реализация для понимания:

```
const inputNameLabel = document.createElement('input')
inputNameLabel.type = 'text'
inputNameLabel.name = 'userName'
inputNameLabel.placeholder = 'Введите ваше имя'
```

Как добавить placeholder?

Comment: И что с вариантом не так?

Comment: Работает https://jsfiddle.net/sq1o8td9/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский У меня не работает, выдает ошибку.

Comment: Надо говорить сразу какую ошибку где и когда, а не ждать, когда из вас эту информацию тянуть будут

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputNameLabel = document.createElement('input')
inputNameLabel.type = 'text'
inputNameLabel.name = 'userName'
inputNameLabel.placeholder = 'Введите ваше имя'
document.body.append(inputNameLabel);
```